# Выпадающий div двигает другой div вниз

Tags: css

Я хочу реализовать блог ответы часто задаваемые вопросы.

Моя проблема заключается, в том, что я не знаю как можно сделать чтобы при раскрытии блока, он не двигал блок который под ним вниз. Я пытался да классу `left-panel` свойство `position: relative;`, а его дочернину классу свойство `position: absolute;`. Но они слепились в одном мести. И я не смогу их разделить в столбик.

```css
.questions {
    display: flex;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.left-panel {
    max-width: 225px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.question {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #f8f4fa;
    position: relative;
    height: 60px;
}

.question:hover {
    border: 2px solid #c42f33;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    height: 270px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.question:hover .question-description {
    display: block;
}

.question-title {
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #2f2f2f;
}

.question-description {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px;
    display: none;
    color: #4f4f4f;
}
```

```html
<div class="questions">
  <div class="left-panel">
    <div class="question">
      <div class="question-title">В чем преимущество покупки машины на аукционе?</div>
      <div class="question-description">
        Покупатель имеет возможность получить достоверную информацию об автомобиле: история, дефекты, ремонты. Машина получает точную оценку состояния кузова салона. Также в числе плюсов - огромный выбор.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="question">
      <div class="question-title">Как проходит оплата?</div>
      <div class="question-description">
        Оплата, проходит в три этапа.
        <p>1. Аванс 30 тыс. руб. при заключении договора</p>
        <p>2. Расходы (стоимость автомобиля на аукционе плюс все расходы связанные с учетом доставки)</p>
        <p>3. Расходы по России (Таможенное оформление + доставка ТК по РФ)</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="question">
      <div class="question-title">Есть ли дополнительные платежи сверх договора?</div>
      <div class="question-description">
        Доставка автомобиля в Россию занимает от 30 дней с момента покупки выбранного авто.
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучше position: absolute задать собственно выпадающей части, а именно - скрытому блоку question-description. Также ему надо добавить z-index, чтобы он перекрывал лежащие ниже элементы.

При этом высоту у question менять не надо - именно изменение высоты и толкает вниз соседние блоки.

```css
.questions {
    display: flex;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.left-panel {
    max-width: 225px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.question {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #f8f4fa;
    position: relative;
    height: 60px;
}

.question:hover {
    border: 2px solid #c42f33;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.question:hover .question-description {
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid #c42f33;
    border-top: none;
}

.question-title {
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #2f2f2f;
}

.question-description {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px;
    display: none;
    color: #4f4f4f;
    position: absolute;
    left: -2px;
    right: -2px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="questions">
  <div class="left-panel">
  
    <div class="question">
      <div class="question-title">В чем преимущество покупки машины на аукционе?</div>
      <div class="question-description">
        Покупатель имеет возможность получить достоверную информацию об автомобиле: история, дефекты, ремонты. Машина получает точную оценку состояния кузова салона. Также в числе плюсов - огромный выбор.
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="question">
      <div class="question-title">Как проходит оплата?</div>
      <div class="question-description">
        Оплата, проходит в три этапа.
        <p>1. Аванс 30 тыс. руб. при заключении договора</p>
        <p>2. Расходы (стоимость автомобиля на аукционе плюс все расходы связанные с учетом доставки)</p>
        <p>3. Расходы по России (Таможенное оформление + доставка ТК по РФ)</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="question">
      <div class="question-title">Есть ли дополнительные платежи сверх договора?</div>
      <div class="question-description">
        Доставка автомобиля в Россию занимает от 30 дней с момента покупки выбранного авто.
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Вот так ?

```css
.questions {
    display: flex;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.left-panel {
    max-width: 225px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.question {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #f8f4fa;
    position: relative;
    height: 60px;
}

.question:hover {
    border: 2px solid #c42f33;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    height: 270px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 300px;
}

.question:hover .question-description {
    display: block;
}
.question-title {
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #2f2f2f;
}

.question-description {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px;
    display: none;
    color: #4f4f4f;
}
```

```html
<div class="questions">
  <div class="left-panel">
    <div class="question">
      <div class="question-title">В чем преимущество покупки машины на аукционе?</div>
      <div class="question-description">
        Покупатель имеет возможность получить достоверную информацию об автомобиле: история, дефекты, ремонты. Машина получает точную оценку состояния кузова салона. Также в числе плюсов - огромный выбор.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="question">
      <div class="question-title">Как проходит оплата?</div>
      <div class="question-description">
        Оплата, проходит в три этапа.
        <p>1. Аванс 30 тыс. руб. при заключении договора</p>
        <p>2. Расходы (стоимость автомобиля на аукционе плюс все расходы связанные с учетом доставки)</p>
        <p>3. Расходы по России (Таможенное оформление + доставка ТК по РФ)</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="question">
      <div class="question-title">Есть ли дополнительные платежи сверх договора?</div>
      <div class="question-description">
        Доставка автомобиля в Россию занимает от 30 дней с момента покупки выбранного авто.
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, хочу упомянуть, что задавать фиксированную высоту блока- плохая идея, особенно когда в блоках может быть разное количество текста.
А если перейти к сути вопроса, то нужно для question-description задать абсолютное позиционирование и сдвинуть его в низ блока question.

```
    .questions {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.left-panel {
  max-width: 225px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.question {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #f8f4fa;
  position: relative;

  &:hover .question-description{
     display: block;
  }

  & .question-title {
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #2f2f2f;
  }

  & .question-description {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    color: #4f4f4f;
    border: 2px solid #f8f4fa;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 0;
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
}
```